# Ubuntu 11n_disable=1 Network Doesn't Work

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, iwlwifi

I am experiencing the network speed low issue. There is a `options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1` line in my `/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf` file. With that line, my network link speed is dead on 54 Mbps, the actual speed is like 20Mbps.

I tried to remove that line. After removal (or set to `11n_disable=8`), I can see from the wifi adaptor, the link speed has increased to ~700Mbps. However, I lost the network connection even the wifi is connected. I can't open any web page and ping any ip.

I don't know what is going on, anyone knows what happened?

`lshw -C network` shows:

```
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:3a:00.0
       logical name: wlp58s0
       version: 1a
       serial: dc:71:96:33:46:4f
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.4.0-73-generic firmware=50.3e391d3e.0 ip=192.168.1.5 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:19 memory:c8100000-c8103fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection (6) I219-V
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.6
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
       logical name: enp0s31f6
       version: 11
       serial: 04:0e:3c:47:af:4a
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k firmware=0.5-4 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:146 memory:c8200000-c821ffff
  *-network:0
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       logical name: veth714e766
       serial: 8e:22:ba:18:a2:43
       size: 10Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=veth driverversion=1.0 duplex=full link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Gbit/s
  *-network:1
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: veth4b7cee6
       serial: 02:56:a7:d9:5a:d3
       size: 10Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=veth driverversion=1.0 duplex=full link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Gbit/s
  *-network:2
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 3
       logical name: vethaac915d
       serial: f6:e8:eb:ab:17:d0
       size: 10Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=veth driverversion=1.0 duplex=full link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Gbit/s
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.
```

`sudo lshw -class network -short && nmcli device status`  shows:

```
H/W path           Device          Class          Description
=============================================================
/0/100/1c.7/0      wlp58s0         network        Intel Corporation
/0/100/1f.6        enp0s31f6       network        Ethernet Connection (6) I219-V
/2                 veth714e766     network        Ethernet interface
/3                 veth4b7cee6     network        Ethernet interface
/4                 vethaac915d     network        Ethernet interface
DEVICE           TYPE      STATE        CONNECTION      
wlp58s0          wifi      connected    Jason 5G        
br-539ba476673f  bridge    connected    br-539ba476673f 
docker0          bridge    connected    docker0         
enp0s31f6        ethernet  unavailable  --              
veth4b7cee6      ethernet  unmanaged    --              
veth714e766      ethernet  unmanaged    --              
vethaac915d      ethernet  unmanaged    --              
lo               loopback  unmanaged    --
```

`ping -c3 192.168.1.1` returns:

```
PING 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.1.5 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable

--- 192.168.1.1 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, +1 errors, 100% packet loss, time 2041ms
pipe 3
```

`ping -c3 8.8.8.8` returns:

```
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.1.5 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.5 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.5 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, +3 errors, 100% packet loss, time 2029ms
pipe 3
```

`ls -al /etc/resolv.conf` returns:
`lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 39 Mar 11  2020 /etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf`

I tried to open my router page `192.168.1.1` but it won't open. I tried using my iPhone hotspot but it's the same. Network connected but no internet.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of these terminal commands; `ping -c3 192.168.1.1` and also: `ping -c3 8.8.8.8` and finally: `ls -al /etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: @chili555 I updated with the output for the commands you ask, thanks.

Comment: Although you appear to be connected; that is, you have an apparently valid IP address, you are not. My we also see: `sudo dmesg | grep -e iwl -e wlp` As the result is probably lengthy, paste the output here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: @chili555 I think you are right, it might look like it is connected but in fact it may not. Here is the output from `sudo dmesg | grep -e iwl -e wlp` https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/jmmjsgzhv9/. I have no idea why I enabled the 11n mode it will stop working. With the `options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1` the log is https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/pz92Qq2S2Q/

Comment: This bug suggests that the error is related to frames sent by the access point: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=203593 Please let us see a paste of: `sudo iwlist scan` Also: `sudo dpkg -s linux-firmware` and: `uname -r`

Comment: @chili555 Thanks for your reply, here is the return of `sudo iwlist scan` https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/855cvdZfFN/ and the output for the rest of the commands
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Yc3gS5C5xQ/

Answer (score 0):

First, we note that the driver loads an older firmware version. As well, your installed firmware version is outdated. Let’s update it. With a working internet connection by ethernet, tethering or whatever means possible, open a terminal and do:

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.190_all.deb    
sudo dpkg -i linux-firmware*.deb
```

Reboot. Is there any improvement? If not, please show us:

```
sudo dmesg | grep -e wlp -e iwl
```

Paste the output as above and give us the link.

**EDIT**: The symptoms are unchanged. Let’s try another driver parameter. From the terminal:

```
sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi
sudo modprobe iwlwifi disable_11ax=Y
```

If this resolves the issue, make it permanent:

```
sudo -i
echo “options iwlwifi disable_11ax=Y”  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
exit
```

**EDIT2**: This message:

> FATAL: Module iwlwifi is in use.

,,,suggests that your iwlwifi.conf file is incorrect. Please change it to read:

```
# /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
# iwlwifi will dyamically load either iwldvm or iwlmvm depending on the
# microcode file installed on the system.  When removing iwlwifi, first
# remove the iwl?vm module and then iwlwifi.
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211
options iwlwifi disable_11ax=Y
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my firmware is outdated. I updated it using your command. After reboot, the internet speed has no change. Also if I remove the `11n_disable=1` the network will have no connectivity. https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/KQgZw9SHy7/ this is the dmesg.

Comment: Please see my edit above in a few moments.

Comment: `sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi` returns `modprobe: FATAL: Module iwlwifi is in use.`. I then added the option into the file and reboot, the speed is remain slow. If the `11n_disable` is removed, the connectivity will be gone. I seen someone who suffered the similar issue but he didn't really solve it. He reinstsalled the Ubuntu instead. I feel it should be the driver or the firmware issue but can't confirm.

Comment: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1782201#p1782201 this guy has a similar issue. He solved it by upgrading some of the packages and deleting the `11n_disable` option. I tried but I don't have the packages he list.

Comment: The primary thing that the archlinux post suggests is to update the kernel version to 4.16.4 where he suggests that the issue is fixed. You are already at kernel version 5.4. Also, the device at archlinux is an Intel 9260; you have an AX200. They are different devices with different firmware.

Comment: With the parameter `options iwlwifi disable_11ax=Y` in place, does dmesg still report Unhandled alg: 0x707?

Comment: Please see another edit in a few moments.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124397/discussion-between-jason-liu-and-chili555).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sudo echo "options iwlwifi disable_11ax=1"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf

sudo reboot
```